# What do you call people filmed in a documentary?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

If I'm watching a documentary about real people, can I say
*"The main character of this documentary is a very determined person..."*

Can I apply word *"character"* to real people, or it's only about made-up/fabulous characters from films/novels/fairy tales etc?

Answer (score 9):

You would generally use **character** to reference either someone fictional or fictionalised, or to refer to a real personal's personality. In your example, I'd suggest using **subject** rather than *character*.

Comment: I like this as an answer to the question, what do you call the main character or a documentary, but you might want to expand it to cover all the other "characters" in a documentary.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answer saying you should use **main subject**. You could probably also use **protagonist** in this context. However, **character** can refer to a real person, if you're describing them as some kind of eccentric/amusing person, often as someone you'd only find in a particular place, as in "The main subject of this documentary is a real New York **character** who feeds bagels to pigeons in Times Square."

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using, "Commentator" over actor.

Comment: The subject of a documentary might not ever make a comment.